# PHP calculate half of 8 hour working day

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

We have `Moodle` `plugin`, where we add the `travel time` of each employee. 
Until now, we calculated the duration of the travel time in `days`, as we added the data for every employee only in such form `timepickup`- 21.10.2105 `timereturn`-23.10.2015.

The data was being added in the function here:

```
$user->timepickup = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $timepickup);
$user->timereturn = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $timereturn);
```

And the calculating of the travel time here:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime($employee->timepickup);
$datetime2 = strtotime($employee->timereturn);
$interval = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
```

As you can see, we add the option to import the `exact time` in `hours` and `minutes` of the `timepickup` and `timereturn`.

How to calculate the travel time and display it in `days` and `half days` (we assume, that `half day` are `4 hours` from the `8 hour` working day.

So instead of travel time `1 day(s)` for adding `timepickup`- `21.10.2105 08:00` `timereturn`-`23.10.2015 12:00`, we will have displayed `0,5 day(s)`.

Comment: Do you round up to the nearest half day, so that `08:00-12:00` is 0,5 day but `08:00-12:03` is 1 day?

Comment: I would use as benchmark `4,5` hours for `0,5` day and more than that for `1` day.

Comment: I made a mistake calculating the half day. See my updated answer.

Comment: Just saw it, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
$pickup = strtotime($employee->timepickup);
$return = strtotime($employee->timereturn);
$timediff = ($return - $pickup) / 3600;

$days = floor($timediff / 8);
$halfday = ($timediff - $days * 8) / 4.5;

$days += $halfday < 1 ? 0.5: 1;
```

It's a bit crude, but you'll end up with adding a half day if the remainder  of the time difference is 4.5 hours or less, and adding a whole day if the remainder is larger than 4.5.

Comment: Until now we added the same `date` (for example 20.20.2015 10:00 - 20.20.2015 12:00, and you get 0,5 days) but if I use the same code for difference based not on the same date, it shows `false` results. For example: 05.20.2015 16:05 - 10.20.2015 12:04, we get difference of 14,5 days. We have `working day` of 8 hours per day,where the travelling takes place.

Comment: Which month is the 20th? Anyway: This is a much more complex issue. This calculation works if you count every 8 hours as 1 work day, but if you cannot have more than 1 work day per 24 hours you need to either change the formua, or create a function that calculates time per day then adds it up. What happens if someone has a 16 hour work day? Do you count it as two days? Do you stop counting at 1 day? How does that work?

Comment: The month was 10th, sorry for that. The work day should be from 8 am until 4 pm . The time is fixed, no one will have more than 8 hours per day. So if you have The period between `05.10.2015 15:05` - `10.10.2015 10:04`, you should be able to display as result `4,5` `work days` (4 full work days and the 3 hours, which we count as 0,5 work day)

Comment: I would ask this as a separate question since the requirements have changed.